# PHP - consecutive page visits

Tags: php, mysql

my question is simple : How can I count how many consecutive days visitor have visited my site (php), any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple:

Just have some concept of either logging in, or a persistent cookie (logging in is more reliable since they can clear cookies). Then in your database have a field for "last logged in". If the last logged in field matches yesterday's date, increment your consecutive visit count, otherwise reset it.

**EDIT**: it's probably obvious, but make sure you update the "last logged in" field after you check it to be today, otherwise every time they load the page it'll increment the count!

**EDIT**: a quick example may look something like this (psuedo code):

```
// first you need to set $last seen from the DB..
// first you need to set consecutive from the DB too..
// once you have, you can do something like this.
if(strtotime('-1 day', date('Y-m-d')) == $last_seen) {
    $consecutive = $consecutive + 1;
    mysql_query(sprintf('UPDATE user SET last_seen=NOW(),consecutive=%d WHERE id=%d', $consecutive + 1, $id)); 
} else if(date('Y-m-d') == $last_seen) {
    // ok, they logged in today again, do nothing.
} else {
    $consecutive = 0; // only really needed if you plan on displaying it to the user
                      // later in this script
    mysql_query(sprintf('UPDATE user SET last_seen=NOW(),consecutive=0 WHERE id=%d',$id)); 
}
```

Comment: "If the last logged in field matches yesterday's date, increment your consecutive visit count"- This is what i need, thank you buddy. And yes, i forgot to mention that i have already a user system (reg,log).Thanks for your answer buddy.

Comment: can you explain it little more, what check i need to do and when i need to increment my count.Thanks

Comment: @Doolkin: I've added a quick example of the concept. It's possible it's not perfect, but I think it demonstrates the idea.

Comment: Could you change the `elseif` to: `elseif(date('Y-m-d') != $last_seen){` to cut put the `$consecutive = 0;` and cut out an else?

Answer (score 1):

cookies

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["identifier"])){
   // log as existing user
}else{
  setcookie('identifier', $id_value, ...
}
```

It wont work if people clear there cookies, which is why they clear cookies.

Comment: Ye, cookies are good way, but its not 100% useful. As you said because people can clear cookies. Thanks for your response anyway buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use pluggable traffic analitic tools, commercial or less like Google Analitics.